# SQL update that seems to require GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an update I'd like to make to a table, something like

```
UPDATE mytable
LEFT JOIN worker ON first=worker_first_name && last=worker_last_name
GROUP BY CONCAT(first, '%%', last)
SET taint = COUNT(pkey) > 1;
```

But of course the table_reference in UPDATE does not allow GROUP BYs.  How can I set this column?  It's just checking if the first/last name combination occurs at most once in the other table.

Comment: MySQL also doesn't allow updating a table from which you're selecting.

Comment: @Marc - unless you use it in a separate context

Comment: True, but this query would seem to be updating mytable.taint while selecting from it for the mytable.first/mytable.last fields (and they have to be from mytable, otherwise joining up with worker makes no sense whatsoever).

Comment: @Marc - the intention is to count the records from workers, which is why the join is necessary

Comment: Not complaining about the join, just that the update is being done on a table involved in the join, e.g. you're writing to a table from which you're selecting - which MySQL doesn't allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable
INNER JOIN (
  select first, last, COUNT(pkey) > 1 Result
  FROM mytable
  LEFT JOIN worker ON first=worker_first_name AND last=worker_last_name
  GROUP BY first, last) OTHER
    on OTHER.first = mytable.first
   and OTHER.last = mytable.last
SET taint = OTHER.Result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET taint = ((select count(pkey) from worker where worker_first_name = first and worker_last_name = last) > 1)
```

But I'm guessing performance might leave something to be desired.  There might be a more performant way.

Comment: That will touch every MYTABLE row - with the left JOIN, the value could either be zero or NULL if there's no match.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: The intent was that if there was no match (or just one match), taint would be false.

Comment: Yeah - I said there was probably a more performant answer.  Looks like cyberkiwi got it for you :)

Comment: Hey - cyberkiwi's answer was far better, you accepted the right answer :)